# Turn plotly button a different color on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I added a new button in my plotly modeBar but I want it to stay a different color when it is clicked on. To show a change in "activeness," so when you click on it, it changes color and shows that it is active and when you click again it gets disabled and goes back to the default color. I am using reactJs.

Comment: Could you provide some related code? Which may help a lot

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
const COLORS = ['black', 'white', 'orange', 'red', 'purple'];
const DEFAULT = "gray";
ChangeColor = () => {
    let rand_color = Math.floor(Math.random()*COLORS.length);
// isDisable should be a state of type boolean set to false by default
if(!isDisable){
   this.setState({ button_color: COLORS[rand_color] })
}else {
   this.setState({ button_color: DEFAULT })
}

}
```

hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a param 'toggle' for Plotly modeBar buttons, here is an example

```js
{
    modeBarButtonsToAdd: [{
        name: 'New custom button',
        icon: Plotly.Icons.movie,
        click: () => console.log('something happened'),
        toggle: true // The icon color will change according to the activeness
      }]
}
```

Tested with Plotly 1.57.1